# How to set up remote docker so that i can run docker command remotely without installing docker on my host

Tags: docker

How I can run docker commands remotely without installing docker on my host?
I tried installing docker in docker container but that did not fulfil my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first Question and i wanted to share the answer so that it can fulfill the other's requirement.

Below Step needs to be followed.

## Docker host

1. Login to your docker host(where you have already docker installed and wanted to use as remote docker host).
2. Pull the below docker image. 
   `jarkt/docker-remote-api`
3. go to below location on your docker host. 
   `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`
4. add the below command in execstart line 
   `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:<port> -H unix://var/run/docker.sock`
5. run the below command 
    
   `systemctl daemon-reload` 
   `service docker restart`

Now follow the below steps in docker client(the machine you want to run the docker command remotely)

1. Login to docker client.
2. download the docker binary (https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/) extract the tar file and find the Docker**file** (not directory) in extracted tar folder and place to docker client (any location)
3. run the docker command remotely now in below format
   go to directory where you have placed Docker**file** then hit the command as `docker -H=<remote_ip>:<port> images, ps, build, stop start, exec` etc.
   E.g.: `docker -H=10.210.X.X:XXXX images` (it will list out your all docker images which is present locally on your docker remote host)

Thanks,

Comment: Remember that **anyone who has network access to your system now has unrestricted root access to it**.  They are totally free to read your password file and ssh keys, install key loggers and network sniffers, and start cryptocurrency miners and worse.  I'd highly recommend to **never set the dockerd -H tcp://... option at all** for security reasons.